# (Not) closing question for Spells with Concentration vs Spells with Thunder/Lightning Damage

Tags: discussion, list-questions

This question:

[Question about Spells with Thunder/Lighting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/86316/is-there-a-list-of-cleric-and-wizard-spells-that-deal-lightning-or-thunder-damag)

was closed by @SevenSidedDie and others for being too broad.

This question has 5 votes and is open:

[Question about Spells with Concentration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76273/is-there-a-list-of-concentration-spells).

I edited my question to be almost the same as the other, but that still didn't change the evaluation.

Concentration and Thunder/Lighting damage are just attributes of 5e spells, I fail to see a difference between the two that would explain the different treatment they get here.

In comments, @SevenSidedDie refused (as is his right, of course) to tell me the difference between the two, as in why one should stay open while the other one should be closed. Maybe someone else can explain this to me?

Comment: See: [What are list questions?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/what-are-list-questions)

Comment: As a note to readers, soon after this meta was posted the second Q&A mentioned was (rightly, to my thinking) closed as too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also keep in mind that "these other questions aren't closed" doesn't mean they're good questions.  They might be from e.g. 2010 before we were clear on stuff.  They may just have snuck by.  Mods don't see every single question and answer on the site and the community doens't respond the same way to every single question and answer on the site.  "Why is it different" is often "no good reason, except for different timing and participants."  (Like, I largely ignore 4e questions due to my inveterate 4e-hate so those question-examples that are 4e I wouldn't come across unless there were flags or other problems that would require my intervention.)

Comment: Yeah, "no good reason, except for different [...] participants" was pretty much my assumption too, especially given the constellation.

Comment: @Mala “different timing and participants” is referring to different voters being involved; different voters mean different people's judgements were used to judge the question. It is not referring to whether the question was asked by **you** or not; mxyzplk is not saying that you are blackballed or deliberately being given worse treatment, [as you appear to have misinterpreted it to mean](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31532472#31532472).

Comment: Indeed, I meant that as the years wear on, different people are there to vote on questions, and as site mores change, those votes seem "different" than a previous question.

Answer (score 6):

The other question is a tool recommendation that was asked before tool recommendations became off-topic. I have voted to close accordingly.

Note that in both cases, the question could have been either a too-broad list question or a tool-recommendation question. The question about concentration was treated as a tool-rec, and yours was treated as a list question, but now that tool-recs are off-topic it doesn't really make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

It was originally closed because it was asking RPG.se to create a list, but it was the kind of list that would continue growing over the years. A list question that needs regular maintenance for its answers to stay correct is off-topic for RPG.se.

As a general guideline, SEs want “timeless” questions—questions that will always be asked, and that have answers that will always be useful. List questions that have answers changing over the years aren't timeless; but neither are list questions with an arbitrary cut-off date.

(RPG.se is okay with some questions being unaskable here. There are *lots* of places on the internet where questions can be asked, so RPG.se doesn't need and doesn't try to accommodate questions that don't benefit from the peculiar mechanics of a Stack.)

It might get reopened now. We'll see what the community thinks, as measured by reopen votes cast.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43576/discussion-on-answer-by-sevensideddie-not-closing-question-for-spells-with-con).

Comment: The "timeless" argument may be incorrect, discussing this in the linked meta.